# Job ad displayed but "no longer accepting applications"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I'm getting [an ad displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/134900/front-end-web-and-app-software-engineer-pingyo-inc?med=clc) and, whilst not interested myself, I happened to click on it only to discover that it says in red at the top:

> This job is no longer accepting applications.

Why do we show those ads to the users? Is it a bug and where should I report it, in such case. Or is it a feature? What is it good for, if so?

Comment: Was this an ad shown from a question page? Or from job search on /jobs?

Comment: @DeanWard Question page. Sorry if I was unclear. I mentioned that I wasn't looking for a new job, assuming that the only reason to visit SO other than that would be questions/answers. My bad.

Comment: no problem, just so I can tag the question so the right people see it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can sometimes happen if certain conditions are met. It's usually not a bug, rather a limitation of the system, which results from a latency-vs-freshness tradeoff we have to make in ads serving.

It stems from the fact that the data structures used for serving the actual job ads are different than the *master* ones about jobs. Furthermore, there's a slight delay between when a job is modified and when the serving data structures get updated. In technical terms, the former are [eventually consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) with the *master* data set. Jobs have a period they're active, and we use that to not serve them for more than they should. But sometimes a job is cancelled before its period is up, and in that case we'll end up serving it for more than we should, and direct people to a job which isn't active anymore.

I've a strong belief that this is what happened in your case. But if you have any extra info, like the actual job involved etc. it would be most welcome. Perhaps there was indeed a bug somewhere.

Comment: **TL;DR**: caching

Comment: As [always](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: @Zanon What is meaning of your comment? It has 16 votes, so there should be good meaning. But I did not got it (my mother language is not English)

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson **TL;DR** means Too Long; Didn't Read.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson You may be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence).

Comment: Well,the link to the actual ad is in the question so feel free to take a look. As for the technical part, the update of the latent service could be invoked upon e.g. the first view after the ad's been cancelled. So the first user would see the ad needlessly but every consecutive one would not be served the side-page ad.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson. `TL;DR` *derives from* "Too Long; Didn't Read", but that's not what it *means*. What it *means* is "in summary".