# Jobs "no longer accepting" for local searches, yet job available on company site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not sure if [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356858/job-ad-displayed-but-no-longer-accepting-applications), and more specifically [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356863/1152524) about caching, is similar to an issue I'm experiencing while looking at local C++ jobs in the San Diego area.

To elaborate; I had a few postings that were rather recent (within the last week or two) and went to start applying after some research of the companies, when the ad displayed the *"This job is no longer accepting applications."* at the top. I payed no mind to the first one or two that displayed this, however, it happened to all of the postings that were specifically local to San Deigo (about 7 or 8 over all).

Further investigation and a few of the postings have the job on their career site still. [Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/176849/software-developer-cp-kelco) that's closed on SO, yet [open on their job portal](https://www.cpkelco.com/careers/opportunities/) (listed as "Software Engineer"), [here's another](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/189879/qt-ui-tools-engineer-brain-corporation) that's [open](https://www.braincorp.com/careers).

I should note that [doing a search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&l=san+diego%2C+ca&d=50&u=Miles) of San Diego within 50 miles, at the time of this posting, gives 32 active/valid results, and other older job postings that offer remote but have San Diego listed didn't exhibit this behavior.

Is this a caching issue, is something else happening, or are they all legitimately closed at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly suspect, this is not a caching issue. As commented on our [April 2018 Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366714/920295), we have been running experiments with job syndication, and we finished one last Friday.

The two listings you included are part of that experiment, and that's why they are closed on our system.

If you want you can send me an email (find my email on my profile) with all the jobs you'd like to apply to and I'll get you their urls so that you can apply offsite.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the reminder about the job-syndication angle; that makes total sense about the listings I _was_ seeing. I thought it ended up well done in the end of its run as I happened to be (am) in the market during that time frame, so I saw a lot more quality results than other portals .. As it happened I've already gleaned the company url's and their subsequent job postings from the dead SO postings, so no extra effort needed on your part, thanks for the offer though!